# Web3.js and local HTML UI

Tags: web3js, dapp-development

So my Mix-ide install seems irrevocably crashed and given that there's no other IDE with integrated UI, I'm forced to face the inevitable learning of authoring HTML UI without much of a web dev background. Though there's plenty of material out there about backend DAPP development, I find almost nil regarding front end DAPP UI development.  I'd like to start learning how to integrate with Mist.  But that aside....

I have the web3.js package in Node and I have `web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));` in my UI html.

Q.  For the purposes of a local test chain, where am I suppose to store this page and what serves it to what URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So for serverless connection of an HTML front-end to a local node, I:

1) dropped web3.js into the DAPP's directory

2) in the HTML included:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="web3.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var Web3 = require('web3');

if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
  web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
} else {
  // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
  web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
}
```

3) started geth with the `--rpccorsdomain="*"` switch to prevent Chrome from blocking the calls.

Comment: Where should be DAPP's directory? is it where html exist? @o0ragman0o

Comment: Same directory as your existing dependant HTML is easiest.  I was doing this just to get light-weight test harness front ends.I'm mostly using Meteor now which has some recommended directory structures.

Answer (score 2):

> given that there's no other IDE with integrated UI

[browser-solidity](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/)?

How about [truffle](http://truffle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for a web framework with contract compilation?

Extratip: [testrpc](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc) to simulate a blockchain the lean way.

Comment: Have been using browser-solidity but don't know if it's possible to integrate/connect a UI as Mix did.  Trying to avoid truffle for now as it constitutes another learning curve while I'm just trying to get the basics of hooking in a UI to a node.  dropping web3.js in the same directory and 'src'ing it in the web page works, but now am faced with CORS problems...

Comment: I understood "integrated UI" more that it provides a form for calling functions

Comment: Talking more front end HTML.  Mix-ide has webkit (or whatever) so you can edit and hook into your contract from the web page. Just looking for quick and dirty ways to do this with a geth on a private test chain without having to set up a local web server.

Comment: got it... now I know what `--rpccorsdomain='*'` is actually for!

Comment: yeah and Metamask should also do what Mix does although not integrated